# Programmatically search a table with jQuery DataTables

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using jQuery DataTables 1.10.9 and jQuery 1.8.3. I'm trying to programmatically search in that, but without success.

I already tried:

```js
function applyFilter(filter) {
    $("#dataTable").filter(filter);
}
```

and

```js
function applyFilter(filter) {
    $("#dataTable").fnFilter(filter);
}
```

Comment: Where are you calling `applyFilter()` from?

Comment: What DataTables version are you using?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan , I'm calling apply filter from an a tag. Something like that <a href="javascript:applyFilter('Vestidos de Noiva')">Vestidos de Noiva</a>

Comment: Your code looks nothing like the code in the DataTables [API reference page](https://datatables.net/reference/api/filter())

Comment: @GyroCode.com DataTables 1.10.9

Comment: @RicardoSilva I think you're looking for the [search()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/search()) function.

Comment: @apokryfos but I'm not finding the search function. When I type $("#dataTable").search in chrome I get undefined

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [`search()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/search()) API method to perform the search, see the code below:

```js
function applyFilter(filter) {
    $('#dataTable').DataTable().search(filter).draw();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
$("#dataTable").dataTable().fnFilter('something')
```